# How do I put Bootstrap into Tiny MCE?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen one place that they had put Bootstrap 3 into Tiny MCE 4. That looked very nice and practical, and I now want to do that too.

I have searched through Google, but not been able to find how to do that.

Do you know? Please share :-)

Comment: You can see print screens here: [Image here](http://postimg.org/image/mzw3h34md/) and here [Another image here](http://postimg.org/image/r4t64074z/)  These images show how I can click the Insert => Bootstrap 3 Components link, and then insert a button or any other style I'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about theming TinyMCE

1. http://foska.pp.ua/codecanyon/mcebs/
2. https://github.com/gtraxx/tinymce-skin-bootstrap

I did a search for tinymce4 skins bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But no, that was not what I was looking for :-) I am looking for an integration of Bootstrap 3 that makes it easy to add custom buttons / div-styles etc. Let me find some images for you to explain.

Comment: You can see print screens here: [link](http://postimg.org/image/mzw3h34md/) and here [link](http://postimg.org/image/r4t64074z/)  These images show how I can click the Insert => Bootstrap 3 Components link, and then insert a button or any other style I'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you take the screenshots from?  Looking at the page source of their site should show you what plugins they are loading.

Would be really interested to find this out for myself.